# addthis button compact: customization

Tags: addthis

I would like to configure the button "addthis_button_compact" on my web site. I don't need 300 services there. I just need about 20 services that I would like to choose myself. And all users my web site can see only 20 services that will be chosen for them.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_16x16_style">
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-502eb95a5c245038"></script>
    <!-- AddThis Button END -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var addthis_config =
    {
          services_compact: 'facebook, twitter, whateveryoufeellike, omegle, etc, etc'
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_16x16_style">
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://s7.addthis.com/
js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa502eb95a5c245038">        </script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config =
{
     services_expanded:"facebook,twitter,google_plusone_share,pinterest_share,yahoomail,blogger"
}
</script>
```

you can choose the service you want to add from this link
[Addthis Basic Service Codes](http://www.addthis.com/services/list)

by add the "Code" of the service you want to show